# How best to Firebase query to observe the change in Bool Property

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a user conversations tree in the Firebase Database. When I run the applications, I get a list of active conversations through the cloud functions (because there is additional filtering performed there). When the user deletes the conversation, I set `isActive = false` and I do not get this conversation when the application is started. Therefore, I need to observe inactive conversations, if any of them suddenly becomes active, then display this conversation in the application. The problem is how to properly make the query.

```
 let query = Database.database().reference().child("chat").child("userConversations").child(currentUserID).queryOrdered(byChild: "isActive").queryEqual(toValue: false)
```

`query.observe(.childChanged)` // for example

For example, such a query does not produce the desired result, since it would work if some other property in the conversation has changed and isActive has remained the same. But when a new message is sent, it is always set to `isActive = true` and the `timestamp` is updated. Of course, I can make a delay and install isActive after a while, but this is a very very bad decision. I also tried several options, but they did not suit me.

I think the most improved solution is to make a query so that it watches when the `isActive` property changes from false to true, but how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I have created a separate branch `chat -> userInactiveConversations -> userID -> Conversation ID` and when the user deletes the chat inside the application, I add a conversation model to this branch. When the application starts, I put the observer to remove from this branch of the model, namely `removeRef.observe(.childRemoved)`. After in this conversation a new message comes from another user or the current user writes from another device, this model is removed from this branch, after which the given observer is triggered inside the application and I start all the necessary functions for the correct processing of the conversation information.